# Since the query parameter includes local specifying the language, all tests using helper methods (like user_path, usre_url) will fail

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a web app with Ruby on Rails.

I recently made the app internationalization. If the URL has query parameter `locale=en`, all texts in the app are English.

In my test code, I wrote many integration tests code like following because of checking all links on the web work well.

```
test "should access all links" do

    :

    get root_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path

    assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    assert_select "a[href=?]", edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path

    :
end
```

However, since I made app internationalization, all tests will fail because the URLs have `locale=en` by default.

I know if I change the code like below, all tests will pass, But I don't think it's a smart solution.

```
test "should access all links" do

    :

    get root_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", "/locale=en", count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", "/help?locale=en"

    assert_select "a[href=?]", "/users?locale=en"
    assert_select "a[href=?]", "/users/#{@user}?locale=en" user_path(@user)
    assert_select "a[href=?]", "/users/#{@user}/edit?locale=en"
    assert_select "a[href=?]", "/logout?locale=en"

    :
end
```

If you know a smarter way to fix it, please write it down.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like:

```
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path(locale: en), count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path(locale: en)

    assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path(locale: en)
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user, locale: en)
    assert_select "a[href=?]", edit_user_path(@user, locale: en)
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path(locale: en)
```